# How to add a background map to a java project?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, java, geotools

I'm new at GIS. I am trying to make a java application that can display a map with certain points. I have achieved this using the geotools library. However, I want to put the map from OpenStreetMap or Google Streets in the background also. I already know that PostGIS can be used with GeoTools. However I don't know where to start. How is the best way to start once I have installed PostGIS?

Hello, I have also come across KML. I'm sorry I'm a beginner. What KML parsing mean, and how can I use this to show a map in my Java Application?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE @meebee. Please use correct upper and lower case when writing your questions. You are asking for other people's help. Make it easier for them to read your text.

Comment: Hello, I edited my post. Do you have any suggestions on where I can start?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add a WMS layer for your background map. The GeoTools tutorial has sections on [adding WMS layers](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/raster/image.html#extra-things-to-try) and [querying databases](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/examples/querylab.html) (Example uses a PostGIS database). You might want to check them out.

Comment: And there are [some WMS servers available serving up rendered OpenStreetMap maps][1] (with varying terms and conditions involved)


  [1]: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS#OSM_WMS_Servers

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "how do I put OSM data into PostGIS so that GeoTools can read it?" then I wrote up some notes on this last year at http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/openstreetmap/index.html.

Once the data is in PostGIS then R.K's links should help you access it using GeoTools.